# Cannot start a new React Native CLI project in WebStorm

Tags: react-native, npm, webstorm

The `react-native-cli` is generating the project fine when I use this command in terminal:

```
react-native init myapp
```

But for some reason WebStorm cannot create new React Native project. When I try I get this error:

```
/home/sagar/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.1/bin/node 
/home/sagar/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.1/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js init bookip
/bin/sh: 1: npm: not found
This will walk you through creating a new React Native project in /tmp/1512313270685-0/bookip
Installing react-native...
Consider installing yarn to make this faster: https://yarnpkg.com
{ Error: Command failed: npm install --save --save-exact react-native
    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:601:13)
    at execSync (child_process.js:641:13)
    at run (/home/sagar/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.1/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js:294:5)
    at createProject (/home/sagar/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.1/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js:249:3)
    at init (/home/sagar/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.1/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js:200:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/sagar/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.1/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js:153:7)
    at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
  error: null,
  cmd: 'npm install --save --save-exact react-native',
  file: '/bin/sh',
  args: 
   [ '/bin/sh',
     '-c',
     'npm install --save --save-exact react-native' ],
  options: 
   { stdio: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
     shell: true,
     file: '/bin/sh',
     args: 
      [ '/bin/sh',
        '-c',
        'npm install --save --save-exact react-native' ],
     envPairs: 
      [ 'PATH=/home/sagar/bin:/home/sagar/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin',
        'LC_MEASUREMENT=ne_NP',
        'XAUTHORITY=/home/sagar/.Xauthority',
        'XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus',
        'LC_TELEPHONE=ne_NP',
        'XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop:/var/lib/snapd/desktop',
        'GDMSESSION=ubuntu',
        'MANDATORY_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.mandatory.path',
        'LC_TIME=ne_NP',
        'GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus',
        'DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-Sq2eReOVZr',
        'DEFAULTS_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.default.path',
        'XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity',
        'LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/sagar/apps/WebStorm-172.3757.55/bin:',
        'UPSTART_SESSION=unix:abstract=/com/ubuntu/upstart-session/1000/1240',
        'QT4_IM_MODULE=xim',
        'LC_PAPER=ne_NP',
        'QT_LINUX_ACCESSIBILITY_ALWAYS_ON=1',
        'LOGNAME=sagar',
        'JOB=unity-settings-daemon',
        'PWD=/tmp/1512313270685-0',
        'IM_CONFIG_PHASE=1',
        'LANGUAGE=en_US',
        'SHELL=/bin/bash',
        'LC_ADDRESS=ne_NP',
        'GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE=/home/sagar/.local/share/applications/jetbrains-webstorm.desktop',
        'GTK2_MODULES=overlay-scrollbar',
        'INSTANCE=',
        'OLDPWD=/home/sagar/apps/WebStorm-172.3757.55/bin',
        'GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID=this-is-deprecated',
        'UPSTART_INSTANCE=',
        'GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge:unity-gtk-module',
        'CLUTTER_IM_MODULE=xim',
        'XDG_SESSION_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0',
        'COMPIZ_BIN_PATH=/usr/bin/',
        'SESSIONTYPE=gnome-session',
        'XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=ubuntu',
        'SHLVL=0',
        'LC_IDENTIFICATION=ne_NP',
        'LC_MONETARY=ne_NP',
        'COMPIZ_CONFIG_PROFILE=ubuntu',
        'QT_IM_MODULE=ibus',
        'UPSTART_JOB=unity7',
        'JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64',
        'XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/usr/share/upstart/xdg:/etc/xdg',
        'LANG=en_US.UTF-8',
        'GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=',
        'XDG_SEAT_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0',
        'XDG_SESSION_ID=c2',
        'XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11',
        'DISPLAY=:0',
        'LC_NAME=ne_NP',
        'GDM_LANG=en_US',
        'XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR=/var/lib/lightdm-data/sagar',
        'UPSTART_EVENTS=xsession started',
        'GPG_AGENT_INFO=/home/sagar/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1',
        'DESKTOP_SESSION=ubuntu',
        'SESSION=ubuntu',
        'USER=sagar',
        'XDG_MENU_PREFIX=gnome-',
        'GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE_PID=20103',
        'QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1',
        'LC_NUMERIC=ne_NP',
        'SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh',
        'XDG_SEAT=seat0',
        'QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=appmenu-qt5',
        'XDG_VTNR=7',
        'XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000',
        'HOME=/home/sagar',
        'GNOME_KEYRING_PID=' ],
     killSignal: undefined },
  envPairs: 
   [ 'PATH=/home/sagar/bin:/home/sagar/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin',
     'LC_MEASUREMENT=ne_NP',
     'XAUTHORITY=/home/sagar/.Xauthority',
     'XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus',
     'LC_TELEPHONE=ne_NP',
     'XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop:/var/lib/snapd/desktop',
     'GDMSESSION=ubuntu',
     'MANDATORY_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.mandatory.path',
     'LC_TIME=ne_NP',
     'GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus',
     'DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-Sq2eReOVZr',
     'DEFAULTS_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.default.path',
     'XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity',
     'LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/sagar/apps/WebStorm-172.3757.55/bin:',
     'UPSTART_SESSION=unix:abstract=/com/ubuntu/upstart-session/1000/1240',
     'QT4_IM_MODULE=xim',
     'LC_PAPER=ne_NP',
     'QT_LINUX_ACCESSIBILITY_ALWAYS_ON=1',
     'LOGNAME=sagar',
     'JOB=unity-settings-daemon',
     'PWD=/tmp/1512313270685-0',
     'IM_CONFIG_PHASE=1',
     'LANGUAGE=en_US',
     'SHELL=/bin/bash',
     'LC_ADDRESS=ne_NP',
     'GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE=/home/sagar/.local/share/applications/jetbrains-webstorm.desktop',
     'GTK2_MODULES=overlay-scrollbar',
     'INSTANCE=',
     'OLDPWD=/home/sagar/apps/WebStorm-172.3757.55/bin',
     'GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID=this-is-deprecated',
     'UPSTART_INSTANCE=',
     'GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge:unity-gtk-module',
     'CLUTTER_IM_MODULE=xim',
     'XDG_SESSION_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0',
     'COMPIZ_BIN_PATH=/usr/bin/',
     'SESSIONTYPE=gnome-session',
     'XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=ubuntu',
     'SHLVL=0',
     'LC_IDENTIFICATION=ne_NP',
     'LC_MONETARY=ne_NP',
     'COMPIZ_CONFIG_PROFILE=ubuntu',
     'QT_IM_MODULE=ibus',
     'UPSTART_JOB=unity7',
     'JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64',
     'XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/usr/share/upstart/xdg:/etc/xdg',
     'LANG=en_US.UTF-8',
     'GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=',
     'XDG_SEAT_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0',
     'XDG_SESSION_ID=c2',
     'XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11',
     'DISPLAY=:0',
     'LC_NAME=ne_NP',
     'GDM_LANG=en_US',
     'XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR=/var/lib/lightdm-data/sagar',
     'UPSTART_EVENTS=xsession started',
     'GPG_AGENT_INFO=/home/sagar/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1',
     'DESKTOP_SESSION=ubuntu',
     'SESSION=ubuntu',
     'USER=sagar',
     'XDG_MENU_PREFIX=gnome-',
     'GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE_PID=20103',
     'QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1',
     'LC_NUMERIC=ne_NP',
     'SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh',
     'XDG_SEAT=seat0',
     'QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=appmenu-qt5',
     'XDG_VTNR=7',
     'XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000',
     'HOME=/home/sagar',
     'GNOME_KEYRING_PID=' ],
  stderr: null,
  stdout: null,
  pid: 20527,
  output: [ null, null, null ],
  signal: null,
  status: 127 }
Command `npm install --save --save-exact react-native` failed.
Done
```

It says `npm` not found when I know it is there.

I have Node 8.9.1 & npm 5.5.1

Comment: Launch WebStorm from terminal instead of desktop/taskbar icon. Any difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like npm is not on your `$PATH`. Do you launch WebStorm from terminal, or from desktop/System menu? In the latter case, WebStorm only sees environment variables configured in `.profile` (login shell), but not in interactive shell configuration files (like `~/.bashrc`). Plus, NVM alters interactive shell configuration files only during installation phase (https://github.com/creationix/nvm/blob/v0.28.0/install.sh#L126)

Possible workarounds:

- **Workaround 1**: make required variables available in a login shell (i.e. for Bash, move them from `.bashrc` to `.bash_profile` or `.profile`).
- **Workaround 2**: run IDE from a terminal
- **Workaround 3**: edit WebStorm desktop launcher and set command to `/bin/bash -l -i -c  "/path/to/webstorm.sh"` (for bash)

Answer (score 0):

Try pointing to your usr/local/bin/node folder.  These are my settings with WebStorm 2017.3 and it worked for me.

[image: Node Interpreter set to /usr/local/bin/node]

Comment: I point to node when creating the project. It dosen't work I am using v 2017.2

Comment: Can you try upgrading to 2017.3?

Comment: I solved it by stating webstorm from terminal. I don't think updating is going to help.

Comment: Great.  I would recommend logging your issue with JetBrains.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/reporting-issues-and-sharing-your-feedback.html

Answer (score 0):

Consider installing yarn to make this faster: `https://yarnpkg.com`

After yarn was installed error is gone.